# Samba does not accept my password

Tags: 12.04, samba, password

I have installed Samba onto Ubuntu 12.04 Server but I can't login as it says my password is incorrect but I am the only user so there are no other passwords.

I have tried changing the password through the terminal but nothing is working.

Any advice for a newbie is very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you setup your share properly? I didn't have mine right apparently. I used these settings: http://ubuntuserverhelp.com/basic-samba-configuration/

Answer (score 62):

This is how I resolved the issue.

from a terminal box type `sudo smbpasswd -a <user name>`
you'll be asked for a password, use your normal one

then you'll be asked for a new "SMB" password... sync it with the usual one by typing in you password again then confirming it...

Shares were instantly accessible from Win7 using Ubuntu user name and password

Comment: THANK YOU!! I encountered this same problem on Linux Mint 17.2!
Now to figure out how to get anonymous browsing working. ;-)

Comment: Solved my problem too. VIrtualBox; Host: OS-X-10.11; Guest: Ubuntu-14.04.

Comment: Isn't this the exact answer you got from @ender?, three months later?

Answer (score 4):

What did you use to change your password?
Samba does not automatically use your user password, your first have to add your user to samba with `smbpasswd -a <user>`

*from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adding-a-user-to-a-samba-smb-share/

Comment: I opened the terminal and typed smbpasswd -a NAME

Comment: i then added a password but i cant get it to work